# Deleting register by Id of entity that has a lot of foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I'm trying to delete a register by the id of the entity `veiculo` through a stored procedure. I pasted the whole procedure below.

When I execute it, I get this error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected ';'

Like, 20 lines if that message on repeat.

I know it's hard to delete a register that has so many foreign keys and additionally, some foreign keys also have foreign keys, but I cannot get to the roots of the error.

I'm guessing if the error is happening at the execution of another stored procedure which happens inside the procedure we're talking about. I know it's hard to see it if you don't know the context, but I'm out of tries, so, here I am.

And my stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Veiculo_Del]
    @Id_Veiculo int, 
    @Id_Usuario int, 
    @Result bit OUT  
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
 
    DECLARE @PreAlteracao nvarchar(MAX) 
    DECLARE @DateNow datetime 
    DECLARE @ErrorMsg nvarchar(100) 

    ALTER TABLE TB_ServicoUnicoVeiculoFaturamento NOCHECK 
        CONSTRAINT FK_TB_ServicoUnicoVeiculoFaturamento_TB_EventoRastreio

    ALTER TABLE TB_Auditoria NOCHECK 
        CONSTRAINT FK_TB_Auditoria_TB_Usuario

    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_VeiculoTransferido', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 

    DELETE FROM TB_VeiculoTransferido 
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL 
       OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo 
 
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_VeiculoTransferido', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_VeiculoTransferido', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow     
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 

    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_GaleriaVeiculo', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 

    DELETE FROM TB_GaleriaVeiculo
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL 
       OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_GaleriaVeiculo', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_GaleriaVeiculo', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow     
        SET @Result = 0 
    END

    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_GaleriaFotoVeic_Veiculo', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 
 
    DELETE FROM TB_GaleriaFotoVeic_Veiculo
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL 
       OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo 
 
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_GaleriaFotoVeic_Veiculo', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_GaleriaFotoVeic_Veiculo', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow    
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 

    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_HistoricoEvento', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 
 
    DELETE FROM TB_HistoricoEvento 
    WHERE ID_EVENTORASTREIO IN (SELECT Id_EventoRastreio 
                                FROM TB_EventoRastreio
                                WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL 
                                   OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo)
 
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_HistoricoEvento', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_HistoricoEvento', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow    
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
     
    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_EventoServico', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 
 
    DELETE FROM TB_EventoServico 
    WHERE ID_EVENTORASTREIO IN (SELECT Id_EventoRastreio 
                                FROM TB_EventoRastreio 
                                WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL 
                                   OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo)
 
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_EventoServico', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_EventoServico', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow  
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
     
    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_EventoServicoMensal', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 
 
    DELETE FROM TB_EventoServicoMensal 
    WHERE ID_EVENTORASTREIO IN (SELECT Id_EventoRastreio 
                                FROM TB_EventoRastreio 
                                WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL 
                                   OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo)
 
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_EventoServicoMensal', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_EventoServicoMensal', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow    
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
     
    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_EventoRastreio', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 
 
    DELETE FROM TB_EventoRastreio 
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo
 
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_EventoRastreio', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_EventoRastreio', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow     
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
     
    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_ServicoAdicionalVeiculo', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 
 
    DELETE FROM TB_ServicoAdicionalVeiculo 
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo 
 
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_ServicoAdicionalVeiculo', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_ServicoAdicionalVeiculo', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow    
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
     
    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_ServicoRasContratado', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 
 
    DELETE FROM TB_ServicoRasContratado 
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo 
 
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_ServicoRasContratado', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_ServicoRasContratado', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow   
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
 
    --DELETE FROM TB_RastreadorVeiculo 
    --WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo 
     
    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_CondicaoPagamentoVeiculo', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 
 
    DELETE FROM TB_CondicaoPagamentoVeiculo
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo 
 
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_CondicaoPagamentoVeiculo', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_CondicaoPagamentoVeiculo', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow   
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
 
    --delete from tb_boletoservico where id_boletoveiculo in
        --(select Id_BoletoVeiculo from tb_boletoveiculo 
        --WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo )
 
    --delete from tb_boletoveiculo
    --WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo 

    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'tb_atendimento', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 

    ALTER TABLE TB_ArquivoAtendimento NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TB_ArquivoAtendimento_TB_Atendimento

    delete from tb_atendimento
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo
 
    ALTER TABLE TB_ArquivoAtendimento CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TB_ArquivoAtendimento_TB_Atendimento 

    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'tb_atendimento', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'tb_atendimento', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow    
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
     
    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_RegistroVenda', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 
 
    delete from TB_RegistroVenda
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo 
 
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_RegistroVenda', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_RegistroVenda', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow  
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
     
    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_AlertaVeiculo', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 

    delete from TB_AlertaVeiculo
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo 
 
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_AlertaVeiculo', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_AlertaVeiculo', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow  
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
     
    EXEC SP_RetornaCampoValor 'TB_Veiculo', @Id_Veiculo, @PreAlteracao OUT 
    SET @DateNow = GETDATE() 

    ALTER TABLE TB_BoletoVeiculo NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TB_BoletoVeiculo_TB_Veiculo
 
    DELETE FROM TB_Veiculo 
    WHERE Id_Veiculo IS NULL OR Id_Veiculo = @Id_Veiculo AND
    @Id_Veiculo NOT IN (SELECT * FROM TB_ServicoRasContratado)
 
    ALTER TABLE TB_BoletoVeiculo CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TB_BoletoVeiculo_TB_Veiculo 
    
    ALTER TABLE TB_Auditoria CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TB_Auditoria_TB_Usuario 

    ALTER TABLE TB_ServicoUnicoVeiculoFaturamento CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TB_ServicoUnicoVeiculoFaturamento_TB_EventoRastreio 
    
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0) 
    BEGIN 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_Veiculo', @PreAlteracao, null, @Id_Usuario, @DateNow 
        SET @Result = 1 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Falha na exclusão do registro. ID: ' + CAST(@Id_Veiculo AS varchar(50)) 
        EXEC SP_Auditoria_Ins 3, 'TB_Veiculo', @ErrorMsg, null, @Id_Veiculo, @DateNow    
        SET @Result = 0 
    END 
END
```

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: "delete a register" - do you mean "delete a row"? Not sure what a register is...

Comment: add a PRINT 'here#1'; PRINT 'here#2'; in front of every EXECUTE call, and see where the error occures in relation to the PRINTs. I'm guessing error comes from dynamic sql, so look for those occurances

Comment: If you can't see where the error is happening, and you suspect its in a child proc, then how do you think we can see it? You're gonna have to employ classic debugging techniques and add prints/selects all the way through to see where it gets to and narrow down the cause. Nothing we can do.